# Term or phrase like "pangram" for more general cases

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase like "pangram" that signifies an example of something that contains all the allowable contents of that class of object:

- "1,234.567809" contains all the generally-allowed symbols for a (US) number
- "1 + 2 × (3 / 4)" contains all the basic [arithmetic operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic#Arithmetic_operations)
- Or an example sentence without the concrete example: "this program is a Python 'pangram': it contains usages of every allowable syntax of the language."

It seems to me that "pangram" itself might fit the bill, but this usage would stretch the definitions a bit:

### pangram, *n.* [(OED)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pangram)

> A sentence containing every letter of the alphabet.

### pangram, *n.* [(M-W)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pangram)

> a short sentence containing all 26 letters of the English alphabet

**EDIT:** although I was hoping there was a more general form of "pangram" for any case that is a "complete example" or something similar, the original impetus for this request was to describe a Markdown document that contained all examples of Markdown syntax to use as a complete test case for a set of CSS styles. Perhaps there is a name for this in the particular domain of programming/markup languages?

Comment: From you description, it looks like you are looking for a terminology.  If that is the case, then please provide the domain of the subject. There are words which represents specific set of objects.

Comment: I was hoping for something more general. I'll edit the question to reflect what originally brought this to mind, however.

Comment: Another bit of inspiration that has come through my mind is "Rosetta stone," whose figurative use has a similar connotation to what I'm looking for, but, again, I think this would be stretching the definition too far and would cause confusion in prose rather than provide clarity.

Comment: You might be able to get away with "CSS-styles Pangram" or similar.

Comment: Probably shouldn't call a pangram for syntax a pantax.  There is some (limited) use of the term *acid test* for examples that are supposed to test complete syntax / lexicon compliance.

Comment: Since 'numeric anagram' is already an acceptable usage, extensions of 'pangram' should also be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

**Catch-all examples, or all-inclusive examples:**

One could use terms, a *catch all example*, or an *all-inclusive example* to describe such an example.  *Pangram* sounds a little too heavy term needing an explanation for itself, when the intention is clearly to illustrate an example that is peculiar about full coverage of concepts to be illustrated. An adjective to word "example" would make it clear that it's something about the nature of the example, and that something is readily highlighted by the meaning of the adjective.

Answer (score 1):

### Exhaustive

You might consider using *exhaustive.*

> [*Merriam-Webster:*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exhaustive)
>
> **Including all possibilities; thorough.**
>
> *'conducted an exhaustive search'*
>
> [*Oxford Living:*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exhaustive)
>
> **Including or considering all elements or aspects; fully comprehensive.**
>
> *‘The guide outlines every bus route in exhaustive detail.’*
>
> *‘The list is by no means exhaustive but it does capture some of the main elements.’*
>
> *‘After **exhaustive testing** they found that a long track in the circuit board had functioned as the antenna.’*

Although this is probably **not** what is meant in the last example above (where I would take *exhaustive* to simply mean 'thorough'), ***exhaustive testing*** is in use as a technical term, and it is one where the meaning should be apparent even to a reader encountering the term for the first time without any explanation:

> [*Technopedia:*](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/19234/exhaustive-testing)
>
> **Exhaustive testing** is a testing or quality assurance approach in which
>   **all possible combinations of scenarios and use/test cases** are used for
>   testing.
>
> In testing software, it is all the possible combinations of
>   every type of input as well as every permutation and variation of how
>   the input is carried out to ensure that everything works as expected.
>   This goes the same for hardware testing—pressing any and all
>   combinations of buttons and switches to determine which ones expose a
>   bug so that it can be fixed.

*Exhaustive testing* refers to a process or procedure, of course, but you are asking for a class [*exemplar*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exemplar) *(a person or thing serving as a typical example or appropriate model:* another word you might consider!)

Something like ***an exhaustive test case*** or ***an exhaustive use case*** should do the job, depending on your exact circumstances.